# How to insert json array into mysql database with multiple records as like db image

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

i have this json array this would insert in mysql table as given image:

[image: My Sql table image]

`[{"F_relation":"Son","F_name":"fhj","F_address_type":"Other","F_address":"55556","F_phone":"556"},
{"F_relation":"Husband","F_name":"fhj","F_address_type":"Other","F_address":"5566","F_phone":"889"},
{"F_relation":"Husband","F_name":"fhj","F_address_type":"Same","F_address":"ak, USA, 5566","F_phone":"89888789"}]`

Comment: so what is issue you are facing?

Comment: First you convert json to array, then after insert array value in database

Comment: Parse and insert. If you're using MySQL 5.7 you can preserve your original data in a JSON column.

Comment: i want to insert it only ! if it may have multiple array they all are comma separated only !

Comment: What have you tried? Show your code, and indicate where you are having a problem.

Comment: What you want is one thing, but **what you've tried** is the important thing to explain when asking on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @tadman is right, we're not here to write the code for you - that's what paid consultants are for. We're all volunteers and are willing to help you solve coding issues, but you have to show what you have tried. It's way too easy to search the web and find answers to the "how do I" type of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json_decode` to convert json string to array.

```
$json='[{"F_relation":"Son","F_name":"fhj","F_address_type":"Other","F_address":"55556","F_phone":"556"},{"F_relation":"Husband","F_name":"fhj","F_address_type":"Other","F_address":"5566","F_phone":"889"},{"F_relation":"Husband","F_name":"fhj","F_address_type":"Same","F_address":"ak, USA, 5566","F_phone":"89888789"}]';
//store the  json string in a variable 

$a=json_decode($json,true); //will convert json string to array
$len=sizeof($a);
for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
    $F_relation=$a[$i]['F_relation']; //retrieve values 
    $F_name=$a[$i]['F_name'];
    $F_address_type=$a[$i]['F_address_type'];
    $F_address=$a[$i]['F_address'];
    $F_phone=$a[$i]['F_phone'];

    //write your query to insert, perform other operation 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
var result = res.d;
```

So you can use it as an array like: `result[0].F_relation`